# I cannot change control's visibility on C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, visibility

I want to change controls visibility on c#, but nothing happens. The controls are in an AspxPopupControl and 3 of them are hidden in design time, 1 of them is visible. I use this code to visible them

```
if (paramType == "Grup")
            {
                gv_Answers.Visible = false;
                trlGroup.Visible = true;
                chkShowItems.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                gv_Answers.Visible = true;
                trlGroup.Visible = false;
                chkShowItems.Visible = false;
            }
```

This code is in a CustomCallBack event of a gridview. So i don't know what to do from this point. It's an easy task but i couldn't handle it.

Thanks for you helps

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint to see if its being hit?

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I can see that the controls' visibilities are changing false to true or false to true, but in the page nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure you are not changing the visibilty anywhere after this?

Comment: i only do it in gridview_customcallback(), the controls are in a popup control, is it because of it?

Comment: Please open a new question if you have an additional problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that you are changing the control's visibility within the ASPxGridView's callback.  The callback response contains only the information about control who initiated the callback and its child controls.  Since the ASPxPopupControl is not a part of the GridView, the problem appears.  The easiest solution is to implement this code within a PostBack event, not a callback.  In this case, everything will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the order your code is executed:

```
trlGroup.DataSource = gnlTreeDColl;
trlGroup.DataBind();
trlGroup.ExpandAll();
```

This should work.

Comment: it didn't work, is it also because of gridview's callback function? Becuase in that callback function, i call a method to bind treelist.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GridView` `enableCallback` property to `False`.

Comment: Why does this work please give an explanation as the comment on its own does not help