# Can't find panel control inside formview Edit mode with Gridview event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Panel visible=false. I have logic that should make the panel viewable if condition is met.
I can't locate the the panel I'm guessing it's because it's not visible. Maybe I'll try on another event and see if I should make the panel visible there. Like the Databound event?

UPDATE****************
Per the comment below on using display:none
excellent suggestion. I thought for sure it was going to fix my issue. However after doing several things, I cannot get the panel style="display:none" to even hide the panel. I know I am in the correct panel on edit as I changed text inside.

I've done several things such as disabled viewstate, hardcoded the style in the code front panel, add.attribute("style",block) at the top of the itemcommand event, put in a testPanel thinking I had something overwriting the visibility somehow....

UPDATE #2***************
I'm totally stumped... This all SHOULD work... So, I did some further googling. Now I may have left out some important information not knowing that it mattered.
- I have a grid view
- The form below is produced by the selectedindex event
- I tried to implement from the following post but no joy
[I cannot change control's visibility on C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862397/i-cannot-change-controls-visibility-on-c-sharp-code)

TESTING RESULTS:
- The Edit Command is getting fired properly
- I removed any controls other than this pacific one
- A panel OUTSIDE the updatepanel can be changed
- I changed the Update Panel "UpdateMode" to Conditional to make sure nothing else was overwriting
even though I know this panel only exists at this point since I just added it.

So is it something with the gridview? Which I added it in below

.aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCollectionEventAll" runat="server">
      <asp:GridView ID="gvCollectionEventDetail" runat="server" SkinID="annualReportGridview" AllowSorting="True"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="odsMRWCollectionDetailByReportId" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" 
      DataKeyNames="MRWCollectionReportDetailId" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" Width="720px" 
      ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="gvCollectionEventDetail_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCollectionEventDetail_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="button" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Select"
                                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#1A3B69" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disposal Method" SortExpression="DisposalMethodCode"
                                        FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="lblDisposalMethod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisposalMethodCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty disposed (lbs)" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWasteQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WasteQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contractor" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
             <ItemTemplate>
                    County:<asp:Label ID="lblSourceCounty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CountyName") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    State:<asp:Label ID="lblSourceState" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StateCode") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    Country:<asp:Label ID="lblSourceCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CountryName") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
             </ItemTemplate>
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
             <EmptyDataTemplate>
                 No MRW Collection details have been entered for this report.
             </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
         </asp:Panel>
         <asp:Button ID="btn_addWasteCollectedRecord" runat="server" Text="Add a New Waste Collected Record" OnClick="btn_addWasteCollectedRecord_Click" />
         <asp:Button ID="btn_addWasteCollectedRecordDone" runat="server" Text="Done Adding Waste Collected Records" Visible="false" OnClick="btn_addWasteCollectedRecordDone_Click" />
                        <br /><br />
     <asp:FormView ID="fvWasteCollected" runat="server" SkinID="annualReportFormview" ViewStateMode="Disabled"
          HeaderText="Selected Waste Collected Detail" DataKeyNames="MRWCollectionReportDetailId" DefaultMode="Insert"
          DataSourceID="odsMRWWasteCollectedDetail" OnDataBound="fvWasteCollected_DataBound" 
          OnItemCommand="fvWasteCollected_ItemCommand" OnItemInserted="fvWasteCollected_ItemInserted"
          OnItemUpdated="fvWasteCollected_ItemUpdated" OnItemDeleted="fvWasteCollected_ItemDeleted">
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <table class="detailstable">
                     <asp:Panel ID="pnlOtherContractor" runat="server" Visible="false">
                          <tr>
                              <th></th>
                                   <td align="left">
                                       Blah Blah
                                   </td>
                           </tr>
                     </asp:Panel>
                 </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void gvCollectionEventDetail_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fvWasteCollected.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
        fvWasteCollected.DataBind();
        pnlMWRCOllectionForm.Visible = true;

        //hide the compost produced add linkbutton
        btn_addWasteCollectedRecord.Visible = false;
        btn_addWasteCollectedRecordDone.Visible = false;

        // hide the edit delete button on fvFeedstockDetail if the annual report already submitted 
        //and the logon user is not ecy staff authorized to edit report ##################################
        Label myLblSubmitDate1 = (Label)fvRptHeader.FindControl("lblSubmitDate");

        LinkButton lbtnWasteCollectedEdit = (LinkButton)fvWasteCollected.FindControl("lbtnWasteCollectedEdit");
        LinkButton lbtnWasteCollectedDelete = (LinkButton)fvWasteCollected.FindControl("lbtnWasteCollectedDelete");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myLblSubmitDate1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            lbtnWasteCollectedEdit.Visible = false;
            lbtnWasteCollectedDelete.Visible = false;
            btn_addWasteCollectedRecord.Visible = false;
        }
    }
protected void fvWasteCollected_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
        {

            ValidationSummaryWasteDetail.ValidationGroup = "WasteReceivedDetail";
            fvWasteCollected.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
            gvCollectionEventDetail.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)fvWasteCollected.DataItem;
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)fvWasteCollected.FindControl("ddl_MRWContractor");
            //Tried Panel pnlOtherContractor = (Panel)fvWasteCollected.FindControl("pnlOtherContractor"); 
            FormViewRow myFormRow = fvWasteCollected.Row;
            Panel pnlOtherContractor = (Panel)myFormRow.FindControl("pnlOtherContractor");

            var s_contractorId = rowView["MRWContractorId"].ToString();
            if (s_contractorId == "0")
            {
                pnlOtherContractor.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of `visible=true` or `false` set Panel to `display:none` and `display:block`

Comment: Updating my post above.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, I made an edit to my orig post. I'm still researching more and it may seem it's an issue due to a gridview event. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it. The form was too early in the lifecycle. in the Databound event, checked if the currentMode was in edit, then I did my checks on the data

```
protected void fvWasteCollected_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormView formview = fvWasteCollected;
        FormViewRow row = fvWasteCollected.Row;
        DataRowView rowview = (DataRowView)fvWasteCollected.DataItem;
        Panel pnlOtherContractor = (Panel)fvWasteCollected.FindControl("pnlOtherContractor2");

        if (fvWasteCollected.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
        {
            var s_contractorId = rowview["MRWContractorId"].ToString();
            if (s_contractorId == "0")
            {
                pnlOtherContractor.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pnlOtherContractor.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button which triggers Edit/Update on the form view. Check whether it has CommandName="Edit" as its attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this 100% working and tested:

Even You set  `Visible="false"` or  `Visible="true"` or

```
 Style="display: none"
```

**Doesn't Matter** you Will definitely get Panel From `FormView's` Row
using this

```
 FormViewRow myFormRow = fvWasteCollected.Row;
 Panel pnlOtherContractor1 = (Panel)myFormRow.FindControl("pnlOtherContractor");
```

**Note**: Your Problem on My PC its working Fine.I Suggest you to set breakpoints and check for each control whether is it null or `myFormRow` is null or not on `fvWasteCollected_ItemCommand` event.

[MSDN REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)